# best practise of creating entitymanager

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jpa

I am using resource local entitymanager with JPA 1 . What is the best practice for creating EntityManager that is

1. Create do job close entitymanager everytime.(Entitymanager not heavy weight but still boring )
2. Create a  entitymanager for every thread and store it as ThreadLocal variable and use it (a-where should i close entitymanager 
   b-Any entitystored in a session scoped bean will be a detached entity because entitymanager which entity in its persistense context closed or belong another thread now.)
3. Store entitymanager in a session bean  and use same entitymanager during session(Sessions unawere of each others )

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not on JPA 2?

Comment: @Matt: why did you delete your answer? It's valid in JPA1 as well.

Comment: @BalusC wasn't sure if that was the case, didn't have time to verify.

Comment: Your `@PersistenceContext` javadoc link even hints *"Since:
    Java Persistence 1.0"*.

Comment: I am not using Spring or seam  I have limited injection enviroment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I create EntityManagers per request and close them in a `ServletRequestListener`.

Answer (score 5):

You should be injecting the `EntityManager` using the [`@PersistenceContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html) annotation. Don't worry about where it comes from — that's dependency injection at work.

Comment: I am using jsf1.2 ,tomcat 6 ,and jpa 1  i think i dont have such an option.I have to move project ejb3  but for now this is not a option

Comment: The annotation was introduced in JPA 1, as BalusC commented (on the question). It has nothing to do with the JSF. You just need to add it as a field into an EJB.

Comment: If i dont care a will see org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist  :)